# Intuitive Approach to the Convergence of Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I understand, generally that the forces determining whether an infinite series will converge or diverge are the rate at which the terms in the series i.e. $a_n$ decrease or increase and the rate at which you add each term. Is there a way to discuss these "forces" in a more precise way or at least a way to explore them more deeply?

EDIT: I understand how to determine and prove that a series will converge or diverge, my question lies more along the lines of what would cause an infinite series to converge.

Comment: There are lots of (precise) theorems that do just that. You will study them in calculus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: Yes. Stop writing "forces" and other new age terms, and research the actual definitions of convergence - which are clear, logical and precise.

Comment: Asymptotics (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis ) would definitely be an area of study in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are many convergence tests that address the properties you bring up. One that comes to mind is the $p$ test, which states the following:

Consider the infinite series $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$. If $p \leq 1$, the series diverges. Else, it converges.

There are many more, but you've probably seen this $p$ test if you've taken Calculus II.